# Sorting in descending order in Excel

Tags: excel

I have data in Excel that requires sorting in ascending order. The data in question is of the form

```
ABC/01/17
ABC/54/17
```

where i need to sort only the values in the middle ie `01` and `54`.

Kindly assist

Comment: The default 'Sort Z to A' will do this, if your prefix and suffix do not change.

Answer (score 0):

use text to column option in Data ribbon to separate the value. then just sort usign sort & filter. after sorting merge them back using =CONCAT()

Answer (score 0):

You can split the first part with

```
=RIGHT(A1;FIND("/";A1)+1)
```

to a second column and sort from there